# Trying to use TSNE from sklearn for visualizing my high dimensional data , but getting import error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I tried this:

```
In [1]: import sklearn
In [2]: from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/intern/<ipython-input-2-9afc8da4e1e3> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

ImportError: cannot import name TSNE
```

actually TSNE is not there in my sklearn.manifold but in documentation of sklearn its must be there.

Comment: You may want to include the version number of scikit-learn and how you installed it. Also your tagging is a little weird. I would remove all tags except python and scikit-learn.

Answer (score 4):

TSNE is not available right now in sklearn. But it is available in the development version of sklearn. Here's how you can build the library and install on ubuntu

```
#Install dependencies for building sklearn
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools \
                      python-numpy python-scipy \
                      libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
sudo pip install cython
git clone "https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git"
cd scikit-learn
make
sudo python setup.py install
```

then try the following in python console

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
```

Comment: Building scikit-learn with make fails due me having the wrong version of cython. I get this message: `Building scikit-learn requires Cython >= 0.21`. Indeed apon checking my cython version is '0.20.1post0'. I tried to upgrade my cython using `sudo pip install --upgrade cython`. However this fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Managed to install Cython by downloading the zip and building it locally. `sudo pip install cython` did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Actually Tsne in included in developer version of skleran .so on upgrading sklearn to developers version . we can use tsne.